# GPS doesn't work offline on Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: gps, airplane-mode

I have Samsung Galaxy S4. I am trying to get the GPS work on offline maps. I am for instance trying this on MAPS.ME app. If I have WiFi or 3G signal, the location works great. However if I turn on the airplane mode, and the location on, the application cannot find my location. I had the issue with Android 4.4 KitKat and recently upgraded to Android 5 Lollipop and the issue is still there.

I am pretty sure it is not an issue with the app because I also tried on Google Maps with a preloaded map and it is the same. I have also downloaded GPS apps such as GPS Test and GPS Status and they all manage to connect with satellites and find a location, even offline. I think that proves that it is not a hardware issue.

I think I might have unselected a Google option somewhere to block the GPS usage (I am usually very careful not to give Google too much data about me)

Any other ideas on fixing this issue?

Comment: How long are you waiting to get a GPS lock? GPS should work with Google Maps, for example, if you are outside in an open space with good visibility and wait several minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If your GPS is set to use AGPS mode, it doesn't work at all when offline for some reason.

Go to Settings - General - Location - Mode - GPS only. I didn't notice at first that it was a selectable option.

Comment: on my phone, it is is exactely the opposite: I manage to get a location in google maps only if the location is set in "High Accuracy' (I guess in this case it is using the network to locate my phone.
... It seems that there is a hardware issue with the gpd of my phone!